# How to use mod_rewrite like this?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite url I have like this

```
/details.php?pid={id}
exam: /details.php?pid={ee76f41017c6f6aa762a2bfb7def83c5}
```

I would like tihs

```
/products/{id}/name
```

I'm try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^cat=(.*)
RewriteRule ^details.php /products/%1? [R=301]
```

and this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]*)$ /details.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: All of a day sorry if make you angry.

Comment: I don't know keyword to search it. My english skill make me hard to understand sorry agian

Comment: I'm not "angry". But you need to show in the question what you have exactly tried. This helps to answer it

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /details\.php\?pid=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /products/%2/name? [R=301,L]
```

The above will change `details.php?pid={id}` to `products/{id}/name`